# Displaying array in single string with comma angularjs

Tags: angularjs, md-autocomplete

I need to represent Given array :

```
    ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado"]
```

as single string separated by commas:

```
    'Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California, Colorado'
```

Comment: Sorry answered the opposite question, to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function:

```js
var myArray = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado"];
var myString = myArray.join(', ');
console.log(myString);
```

Comment: @abc3018 Please mark as an answer if this was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm nowhere near being really good at Angular, but couldn't you just write a js function to do it for you?

And I'm assuming you switched your 2 sentences? Since you want to go from array to string but your first line of code is a string and your second one is an array?

Anyway, this is how I would do it:

```
var string = "";

myStates.forEach(function (state, index, array) {
    if (index === array.length - 1) {
        string += state;
    } else {
        string += state + ", ";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```js
var a = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado"];
var string = a.join(",");
console.log(string);
```